# Issue with state in react using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, state

I have an application that allows the user to select a US state, Once state is selected I pull some data from my firebase database, based on the state the user selected. If the user selects "California" I expect it to pull UFO sightings from California.

Upon render my state is empty. Once I select any state lets say "Washington" my state is still empty. If i choose another state like "California" my results from Washington show up and not California, then if I choose another state like "New York" my results from California will display and not New York.. it continues in this pattern.

Any reason why this is happening? I am missing something. Below is my code, and I can also provide any other information if needed or screenshots.

```
const [ufoSightings, setUfoSightings] = useState([]);
const [userStateSelection, setUserStateSelection] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setUfoSightings([]);
    //referencing firebase db
    const ufoRef = firebase.database().ref("ufos");
    //filter database searching for spacific state user is looking for
    const query = ufoRef
      .orderByChild("state")
      .equalTo(`${userStateSelection}`)
      .limitToFirst(2);

    let allUfo = [];
    query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
      //storing ufoSightings in state
      snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
        allUfo.push(snap.val());
      });
    });
    setUfoSightings(allUfo);
  }, [userStateSelection]);

  ufoSightings.map((item) => console.log(item));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setUfoSightings(allUfo);` will execute before `query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {` resolves. Try the following by moving the `setUfoSightings(allUfo);` inside the `then`:

```
let allUfo = [];

query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
    allUfo.push(snap.val());
  });

  setUfoSightings(allUfo);
});
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Alex,
Thanks! This did fix the problem, something silly I didn't catch. Now when I select "Washington" my UFO sightings for Washington display, but if i select "California" my UFO sightings from Washington get console. Logged THEN my UFO sightings from California get console. Logged. Any reason for this? Basically when a I select Washington I want UFO sightings for Washington to display, and when i select "California" i want my UFO sightings for California to display and not Washington's THEN California's. Hopefully this makes sense. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that when you select Washington, then select California, both Washington AND California are being shown? As in they become combined?

Comment: Exactly. If select Washington, the UFO information displays for Washington. Then when i select a different state like California, my Washington UFO information will display again, then California's will get displayed.

Comment: Before `setUfoSightings(allUfo);` can you try doing `console.log(userStateSelection , allUfo)` after you select California (second option)? Want to understand whether the query is returning only California items.

Comment: ah, what you said just made sense. I needed to set my userStateSelection to an empty string every time useEffect got called so i was not querying multiple states. Hopefully that makes sense. THANK YOU.